# Two cursors on maps at same time in Mapbox GL-JS

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am developing a weather radar viewer using Mapbox. In a certain mode, there are 2 Mapbox maps on the screen at the same time showing different modes of the radar. The maps are locked to each other. When one map moves, rotates, or pans - the other one does as well. I did this by simply passing the properties of one map to the other. In the below screenshot, you will see how they are showing identical locations.

What I want to do is - when the user is hovering the mouse over "map1", I would like an identical (ghost or false) cursor on "map2". Here is what I am looking to do:

(edit: What you are looking at is an actual screenshot. Each map is enclosed in a DIV with 50% width of the screen, if this helps to explain)

[image]

I don't know if this is even possible in Mapbox. Hopefully someone can give some guidance as I can't find any other questions related to this and I really have no code to show without knowing where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attempt to do this inside Mapbox-GL-JS (for instance, by constantly updating the location of a GeoJSON feature layer), I think the performance will be pretty poor.

But since the two views are exactly locked (and presumably the exact same dimensions), you can just do this at an HTML/CSS level. Detect mouse movement on the first map, and update the location of an absolutely-positioned element hovering over the second map to match.

Another approach would be using a `canvas` element overlaid over the second map, similarly updated.

Comment: I already accepted your answer, but this did work using CSS and absolute positioning instead of Mapbox functions. Your assistance in the Mapbox community here is greatly appreicated.